# OneSignal(Flutter) - Getting error when tryping to run on iOS17 - XCode 15

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode, onesignal

I updated my Xcode and migrated onesignal_flutter to 5.0.1. I have also updated pod file as instructed (pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 5.0.0', '< 6.0').

Still, I'm getting this error:
Error (Xcode): Framework 'OneSignal' not found

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

1. Use XCode 15
2. Updated onesignal_flutter: ^5.0.1
3. Run project on simulator

Comment: """
target 'OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'OneSignalXCFramework', '>= 5.0.0', '< 6.0'
end
"""

Maybe you can try this in  ios>Podfile

Comment: Did try that. Not working.

Answer (score 0):

Please update onsignal_flutter version to 5.0.2

Please confirm below codes on pubspec.lock and ios/podspec.lock file

```
  onesignal_flutter:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description:
      name: onesignal_flutter
      sha256: "79add7f791dbb6939a014006d314ea97b281df1ecd484351bce83c00c942246c"
      url: "https://pub.dev"
    source: hosted
    version: "5.0.2"

- onesignal_flutter (5.0.2):
    - Flutter
    - OneSignalXCFramework (= 5.0.2)
  - OneSignalXCFramework (5.0.2):
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalComplete (= 5.0.2)
  - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignal (5.0.2):
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalCore
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalExtension
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalNotifications
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalOSCore
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalOutcomes
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalUser
  - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalComplete (5.0.2):
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignal
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalInAppMessages
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalLocation
  - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalCore (5.0.2)
  - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalExtension (5.0.2):
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalCore
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalOutcomes
  - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalInAppMessages (5.0.2):
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalCore
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalNotifications
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalOSCore
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalOutcomes
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalUser
  - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalLocation (5.0.2):
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalCore
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalNotifications
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalOSCore
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalUser
  - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalNotifications (5.0.2):
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalCore
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalExtension
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalOutcomes
  - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalOSCore (5.0.2):
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalCore
  - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalOutcomes (5.0.2):
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalCore
  - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalUser (5.0.2):
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalCore
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalNotifications
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalOSCore
    - OneSignalXCFramework/OneSignalOutcomes
```

That was working well on my side, MacOS: 14.0, Xcode: 15.0